# RabbitMQ installation in Program files directory is wrong?

Tags: windows, queue, queue-management

According RabbitMQ documentation is highly recommended to not use spaces in installation path. Does it mean that Program files directory for RabbitMQ is wrong?

[Documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html#installer) says:
Installation path must only contain ASCII characters. It is highly recommended that the path does not contain spaces in any directory names.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html#installer

Comment: No, it means that it's highly recommended to not install there and that there can be issues if you do. I don't really see the purpose of this question TBH. You can just test if it works for your use case(s) or just (re)install to a safe dir.

Comment: The purpose of this question is to remove confusion about so trivial use case like installation to Program files directory. Can not believe it...

Comment: It's the opposite of trivial actually - it might work on the 1st sight but have "random" hardly predictable issues. I think only devs could answer this very accurately.

Comment: I mean I never ever install service which have this problem. This means trivial. Trivial for user cause thats the point of services. To make life easy not harder.